# Mysql query to find minimum and maximum of 2 columns where minimum of 1 column must not be equal to zero

Tags: php, mysql, sql, max

Everyone i have stuck on strange problem in mysql. I am a newbie in mysql, hope someone can help me.

I have 2 columns of price in a table.`mrp_price` and `discounted_price` :

```
mrp_price discounted price
 400        000
 500        300 
 600        400
 700        500
 800        600
```

I want my mysql query to return **minimum** as `300` (whatever is minimum in `mrp` and `discounted price` but not to consider 000 values of dicounted price) and **maximum** as `800` (whatever is maximum in `mrp_price` and `discounted_price`).

my output will looks like this:

```
     min(mrp_price) max(mrp_price)   min(discounted_price)  max(discounted_price)
       400                  800           300                      600
```

**I want my final output as :**

```
       min(price)    max(price)
          300             800
```

I want my **final output** with the help of query. I hop i am little bit clear now in making my frnds understand my problem.

Please help,

Comment: What is the type of `mrp_price` and `discounted price`?

Comment: give some example of output what you want, as your question is not clear, and what you have done?

Comment: @ashok_p: OP is clear. He also posted what the expected output is. See [*answer by Notulysses*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24133165/767881)

Comment: why do you say "whatever is maximum in mrp_price **and discounted_price**" wouldn't mrp_price always be greater than discounted_price?

Comment: yes bro mrp price will always be greater than discounted price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(`p`)
 , MIN(`p`) 
FROM (SELECT Min(`discounted_price`) as `p` FROM `table` WHERE discounted_price!=0)
   UNION
   (SELECT Max(`mrp_price`) as `p` FROM `table` )
```

Answer (score 2):

The logic is as follows : select two rows in one and then find maximum and minimum values.

```
SELECT MAX(`t`)
     , MIN(`t`) 
FROM ( SELECT `mrp_price` as `t` FROM `table`
       UNION
       SELECT `discounted price` as `t` FROM `table` ) 
WHERE `t` != 0
```

In case the first column is always greater than the second :

```
SELECT MAX(`mrp_price`)
     , MIN(`discounted price`) 
FROM `table`
WHERE `t` != 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this approach:

```
select least(min(case when discounted_price > 0 then discounted_price else 10000 end),
             min(case when mrp_price > 0 then mrp_price else 10000 end)
            )
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear. Do you want to select the mrp_price where discount is maximum or you want you want mrp_price where both mrp_price and discount is maximum. Same case for minimum. For the earlier case, you can try following query

```
SELECT MAX(mrp_price) FROM *{TABLE NAME}* WHERE discounted price=(MAX(discounted price))
```

Similar query for minimum

```
SELECT MIN(mrp_price) FROM *{TABLE NAME}* WHERE discounted price=(MIN(discounted price)) AND discounted price!=0
```

Comment: Sir, minimum of mrp price is 400 and minimum of discounted price is 300. So i want minimum price as 300.and same of maximum.